# When does a load event of a browser occur?

Tags: javascript, load

Wondering when does a load event occur in a browser? Is it when it receives the header information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

onload is triggered after the entire document, images and all, are loaded.

Some browsers, like Firefox, also have on-content-load events that are triggered after the HTML file is delivered, but before external files like images are loaded.

Answer (score 3):

onload occurs when all the data has been downloaded, including all css, javascript and image files.